# could not find driver(SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema=aas2api_research and table_name=migrations and[...]

Tags: laravel, mysql-connector

I am trying to do a php artisan migrate. I use PHPStorm, windows 11, xampp as a server and php7.4. version. When migrating i get the following error:

```
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

 Do you really wish to run this command? (yes/no) [no]:
 > yes


In Connection.php line 712:
                                                                                                                                                                        
  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = aas2api_research and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')  
                                                                                                                                                                        

In Exception.php line 18:
                         
  could not find driver  
                         

In PDOConnection.php line 40:
                         
  could not find driver
```

My .env file looks like this:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:ADD+G66Hzv/qpuVy0l7o/aeBeB/HRKugz8LrbMT5rmI=

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=aas2api_research
DB_USERNAME=root
```

my config/database.php looks like this:

```
'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
        ],
```

I already did the following:

Inside of the config/database.php i changed the line `'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),` into `'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),`

my enviromental Variables system path has the following line:
C:\Program Files\php-7.4.33-Win32-vc15-x64

After starting XAMPP i searched for my php.ini file inside of http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php. I found it in C:\xampp\php\php.ini.. I restarted my server and it didn't work

I uncommented extension=pdo_mysql. I looked inside of the ext folder, there is no pdo_mysql, i also tried with extension=pdo_mysqli both commented and uncommented

Under the line On windows inside of the following code, i also uncommented the line with ext file. I also tried the relative and the absolute path

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
;extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
```

So basically i tried everything i found on the internet and nothing helped. Has anyone any other idea? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For those with the same problem: My project worked before upgrading my laptop to windows 11. So after doing a clean new download back to Windows 10 everything worked fine again. Hopefully, it will help someone in the future.